# Limiting map size in extended battleships program

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, size

```
print("----BATTLESHIPS 3.0 By NAME----")
print("")
print("")

size = input("Map size: ")
size = size.replace(" ", "")
print("------")

keys = {1:'A',2:'B',3:'C',4:'D',5:'E',6:'F',7:'G',8:'H',9:'I',10:'J',11:'K',12:'L',13:'M',14:'N',15:'O',16:'P',17:'Q',18:'R',19:'S',20:'T',21:'U',22:'V',23:'W',24:'X',25:'Y',26:'Z'}

#COORDINATES
for h in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
  for b in range(1, int(size) + 1): 
    num = [h, b]
    #print(num, end=' ')
#COORDINATES

dict = {}
guess = input("Guess: ")
guess = guess.lower()
guess = guess.replace(" ", "")
print("---")

while guess:

  if guess in dict:
    print("Whoops! You've already hit that coordinate") 

  elif guess not in num:
    print("Woah! That isn't a square!")

  #elif int(guess[1:]) > 10 and int(guess[1:]) >= 1:
    #print("Woah! That isn't a square!")

  else:
    dict[guess]=guess
    print("Hit", guess.upper())

  guess = input("Guess: ")
  guess = guess.lower()
  guess = guess.replace(" ", "")
  print("---")

yn = input("List your guesses? (yes or no)")
yn = yn.lower()

if yn == "yes":

  print("------")
  print("GUESSES:")

  print("---")
  for i in dict:
    print("-", i.upper()) 

elif yn == "no":
  print("Ok, bye!")
else:
  print("---")
  print("Please don't try and trick me. No scores for you!")
```

I am having a lot of trouble with this. I am supposed to create a program that extends a simple program called Bomb's Away. I am trying to limit the size of the map but not doing a very good job. Everything I input says it is not a square.

**Requirements:**

Bombs Away is based on the Battleship Game where two players guess positions on a map. Each position on the map is identified by a Letter-Number location. In the original problem, the program recorded every position the player typed. If the coordinate was already recorded the program said so.

- The user is allowed to set the size of the map. The map is always square. The map cannot exceed the number of characters found in our alphabet (i.e. 26 characters). The smallest size for the map is 5 columns. The program prompts the user to provide the size of the map.
- When entering the size of the map, the program ensures that a valid number has been input. If not the user is presented with a message to input a valid number. The user cannot continue until an acceptable number is input.
- If the user types in valid coordinates, the program stores that information. Design a creative approach to presenting the user that the coordinates have been recorded.
- If the user types in coordinates that don’t exist, creatively present the user a message of this. These coordinates must not be stored. Only valid coordinates are stored.

Comment: what is the problem when you run this code?

Comment: Well it doesn't do what I want it to do. When someone types in the size of the map eg. 20, even if I type a coordinate that fits the requirements of that size it prints "Woah! That isn't a square!"

Comment: The loop for COORDINATES is just repeatedly overwriting a list of two elements. If size was 10 the final value would be ['Z',10]. Probably not what you want for a data structure representing the coordinates.

Comment: I know, how do I fix this?